# Why can't Python decode this valid JSON with escaped quotes?

Tags: python, json, escaping, decode

I have this almost JSON which has something that's only similar to JSON inside:

```py
TEST_LINE = """Oct 21 22:39:28 GMT [TRACE] (Carlos-288) org.some.awesome.LoggerFramework RID=8e9076-4dd9-ec96-8f35-bde193498f: {
    "service": "MyService",
    "operation": "queryShowSize",
    "requestID": "8e9076-4dd9-ec96-8f35-bde193498f",
    "timestamp": 1634815968000,
    "parameters": [
        {
            "__type": "org.some.awsome.code.service#queryShowSizeRequest",
            "externalID": {
                "__type": "org.some.awsome.code.common#CustomerID",
                "value": "48317"
            },
            "CountryID": {
                "__type": "org.some.awsome.code.common#CountryID",
                "value": "125"
            },
            "operationOriginalDate": 1.63462085667E9,
            "operationType": "MeasureWithToes",
            "measureInstrumentIdentifier": "595909-48d2-6115-85e8-b3aa7b"
        }
    ],
    "output": {
        "__type": "org.some.awsome.code.common#queryShowSizeReply",
        "shoeSize": {
            "value": "$ion_1_0 'org.some.awsome.model.processing.ShoeMeasurementBI@1.0'::'org.some.awsome.model.processing.FeetScience@1.0'::{customer_id:\"983017317\",measureInstrumentIdentifierTilda:\"595909-48d2-6115-85e8-b3aa7b\",foot_owner:\"Oedipus\",toe_code:\"LR2X10\",account_number_token:\"1234-2838316-1298470\",token_status:VALID,country_code:GRC,measure_store_format:METRIC}"
        }
    }
}
"""
```

The regex gives me the start of the JSON and I try decoding from there. According to https://jsonlint.com/, it is valid JSON after that point.

So why doesn't Python's JSON module decode it? I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 25 column 156 (char 992)
  File "/Users/decoder/Downloads/json-problem.py", line 44, in read_json
    d = json.loads(line)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/decoder/Downloads/json-problem.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(read_json(TEST_LINE))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 25 column 156 (char 992)
```

Line 25 and character 156 points to the first `\"` in `output.shoeSize.value`.

But why? That embedded value is only *roughly* JSON but it should *not* try to decode it anyway as it is given as a plain string. And the quotes are nicely escaped to not end the string early.

```py
FIND_JSON = re.compile(
    r"\w{3} \d{2} (\d{2}[: ]){3}GMT \[[^]]+\] \([^)]+\) "
    r"org.some.awesome.LoggerFramework RID=[^:]+: "
)

def read_json(line: str) -> str | None:
    if not (m := FIND_JSON.match(line)):
        return None
    line = line[m.end(0) :]
    d = json.loads(line)
    return d


print(read_json(TEST_LINE))
```

I've also tried the [`raw_decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) but that fails similarly. I don't understand.

**Update 1:** To the commenter pointing to a non-escaped double quote, I don't see it. For me after the colon it follows a backslash and then a double quote. And—again—for me, the linter tells me it's good. Is there some copy & paste transformation happening on SO?

**Update 2:** Added the (still missing) code that makes the problem apparent.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Please provide just the string, a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about the code, I meant to add it but the submitted too early.

Comment: you need to understand, the input you are providing us is **ambiguous**. Please just provide *source code* that we can run, e.g. `data = ...` so that `data` accurately reflects **the actual string you are working with**

Comment: Because if I copy and paste the string you posted as an input and assume that it should be treated as a raw string, this parses just fine.

Comment: i.e. I copy-paste the block with your input, and do `TEST_LINE = r"""<paste>"""` then it works just fine. If I don't treat it as a raw string, i.e. `TEST_LINE = """<paste>"""` then it doesn't work, and reproduces the exact error message, but of course, that's because the escapes are applied to the string literal in that definition statement. So the actual string just ends up with unescaped quotes.

Comment: So perhaps the question is, *how exactly are you getting `TEST_LINE`*?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. Sometime one is stupid. Of course I need a raw string! ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not 100% clear how your defining the string but the issue is likely that the escaping of quotes is being processed by python and removed BEFORE its being feed into the json library:

```
data ="""{
"value": "{customer_id:\"983017317\"..."
}'
"""
print(data)
```

prints:

```
{
"value": "{customer_id:"983017317"..."
}'
```

see the escaping is gone. to have python not process the escaping and have it processed by json you need to declare it as a raw string with `r"your_string"`
i.e

```
data =r"""{
"value": "{customer_id:\"983017317\"..."
}"""
print(data)
```

prints:

```
{
"value": "{customer_id:\"983017317\"..."
}
```

which you can then feed into  `json.loads()`  without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is because the embedded string within the "shoeSize" key contains single quotes (') which aren't properly escaped in the JSON. The JSON standard only considers double quotes (") as valid for string delimiters, and your embedded string is mixing both single and double quotes.

To make the JSON valid and decodable by Python's json module, you can replace the single quotes with escaped double quotes in the "shoeSize" value. Here's a modified version of the "shoeSize" key-value pair:

```json
"shoeSize": {
    "value": "$ion_1_0 \\"org.some.awsome.model.processing.ShoeMeasurementBI@1.0\\"::\\"org.some.awsome.model.processing.FeetScience@1.0\\"::{customer_id:\\\"983017317\\\",measureInstrumentIdentifierTilda:\\\"595909-48d2-6115-85e8-b3aa7b\\\",foot_owner:\\\"Oedipus\\\",toe_code:\\\"LR2X10\\\",account_number_token:\\\"1234-2838316-1298470\\\",token_status:VALID,country_code:GRC,measure_store_format:METRIC}"
}
```

After making these changes, you should be able to decode the JSON using Python's json module:

```py
import json

# Assuming modified_json contains the modified JSON string
d = json.loads(modified_json)
```

Comment: No, it wasn't the single quotes. They are not a problem for JSON—not even a special thing as you mention. It was the raw string.